# Drawing visited area in map/image navigation

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, swt, paint

I am using Eclipse RCP with SWT in Java.
I am implementing an image viewer for large multiresoution medical images. These images are similar to maps. They are multi layered (resolutions) tiled images. There is a navigation (also called overview) window at the bottom right corner which displays what part of the image you are looking at.

Now, I have a requirement to track what part of the image the user has seen, and display that in the navigation window using a color mask. So, if user turn on the tracking, a transparent (alpha value 100) black color mask will be shown over the navigation image and as the user will pan through the image, the mask will clear for that much area. It would look something like below:
[image]

To implement this, I have done following in my navigation window class:

```
public void paintControl( PaintEvent e )
{
     e.gc.drawImage( overviewImage );  //draw the overview image in the background
     e.gc.drawRectangle( cameraBounds ); //draw rectangle showing current camera location

     //draw the tracking mask
     e.gc.setAlpha( 100 );
     e.gc.setBackground( blackColor );
     e.gc.fillRect( getClientArea() ); // draws the black mask on the navigation image

     //now how to draw the visited area?
```

My problem is, how do I draw the visited area now? There are two problems:

1. how to track how much area is visited by user. How to maintain this polygon? Any existing algorithm that can help me?
2. To draw this, what will be the best strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region` to maintain the information regarding the visited areas. Every time the user scrolls or scales the main view, you could add the coordinates (rectangle) of the viewed area (scaled as needed) to the region. Then you can fill the whole client area of your navigation window with a proper color and alpha, using the region for clipping it. It seems to be rather a straightforward way.  
 
Another way is to construct a polygon to be drawn, using the Region to determine the intersections of visited rectangles. e.g. for rectangles {x=1,y=1,w=2,h=2} and {x=2,y=2,w=2,h=2} you find the intersection {x=2,y=2,w=1,h=1}, and include to the polygon the corners of original rectangles except the points {2,2} (lower right point of the 1st rect == lower right point of the intersection) and {3,3} (upper left point of the 2nd rect and of the intersection) and additionally include {3,2} and {2,3} (the other two corners of the intersection). Of course, it's only a general idea and it requires further deliberation.

Comment: Thank you so much! The org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region class solved the problem. I add the camera bounds to the region and use it to set clipping on my navigation to draw the seen area.

Answer (score 0):

[Drawing visited area in map/image navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086898/drawing-visited-area-in-map-image-navigation)

Instead of managing polygons for complex algorithms like [scanline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering) and [tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)), you can implement an algorithm that makes use of a simple pixel-map.

In order to track the visited area, you can keep a [binary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) which represents a pixel-map of the displayed image. Initially all elements of the matrix should be `0`, which means no pixel is visited yet. As the user moves the navigation window, considering visited pixels, you should update the corresponding values in matrix to `1` (visited).

I will not go into details about how you can do it with SWT, but you can manage the rendering by updating the alpha values of the visited pixels while the navigation window is moving. You can increase the efficiency of this rendering by applying this update to each pixel only once, since a possible change is one-time and one-way: not-visited to visited. In other words, after a pixel is visited there is no way back. To attain this, maybe you can keep another matrix which shows the pixels that do not need to be updated any more.

Comment: The binary matrix seems to be a good idea. But drawing in SWT is a problem. I have to redraw the complete navigation window whenever the camera moves. I tried redrawing each pixel's alpha using the binary matrix, but that makes very bad performance. Each redraw of navigation window is literally hanging my application.

Comment: Actually you don't have to redraw entire window. As I said this technique can easily be improved. For each movement, just redraw the pixels that changed from zero to one in the matrix.